# Swift Generics/Opaque Types: trying to use protocol conformance to convert between types in a generic function

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, opaque-types

I'm building a `Converter` to convert my `DataObject`s to `ModelObject`s and vice versa. I currently have two functions to do the converting. One for each conversion.

Currently, both of my conversion functions do exactly the same thing with exceptions to the type it takes and the type it returns. I was hoping I could write a generic function that would be able to handle both conversions because, otherwise, the code is exactly the same.

**Here's what I've got:** *Obviously these are simplified examples*

I've built a `Protocol` that contains the requirements for properties and an `init()`. I've implemented this `Protocol`  and its `init()` in both the `DataObject` and `ModelObject`.

**My `Protocol`:**

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var name: String? { get }

    init(id: UUID, name: String?)
}
```

**My `DataObject`:**

```
class DataObject: Object, MyProtocol {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: UUID

    @Persisted var name: String?

    required convenience init(id: UUID, name: String?) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**My `ModelObject`:**

```
struct ModelObject: MyProtocol {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String?

    init(id: UUID, name: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

**Currently:** *This is an example what is currently doing the conversions. I have one like this for each conversion.*

```
static func buildModelObject(object: DataObject) -> ModelObject {
    let returnObject = ModelObject(id: object.id, name: object.name)
    return returnObject
}
```

**Desired `Converter` Function:** *I hope to accomplish something like this.*

```
static func buildObject<O: MyProtocol, R: MyProtocol>(objectIn: O, returnType: R.Type) -> R {
    let returnObject = returnType.init(id: objectIn.id, name: objectIn.name)
    return returnObject
}
```

**And I'm calling it like this:**

```
let object = Converter.buildObject(objectIn: dataObject, returnType: ModelObject.self)
```

Obviously, this isn't working. ***Error:*** "Protocol 'MyProtocol' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself". The error is on the function call. This is the only error XCode is showing me at compile.

*I'm not certain what to do here or how to get it working. I'm not even confident that this error message is even helpful in any way.*

**The Question:**

Is it even possible to accomplish something like this? If so, what am I missing? I'm still very unfamiliar with Swift Generics.

I don't have an issue with using multiple conversion functions as it's still better than getting the entire code base bogged down with Realm specific stuff. But, given that these functions are essentially the same, I'm hoping that Generics might be able to help reduce otherwise similar code into a single function.

***Note:** The `DataObject` is a Realm `Object`. I understand they have cool features like live/managed Objects. We're trying to keep our Persistence layer completely separated from the rest of the app with a single API/Entry Point. This is why I'm using these Converters.*

Comment: Maybe Im not getting the question, but if the whole conversion is just initializing an object from some other object that conforms to `MyProtocol`, why can't you have `init(from another: MyProtocol) {self.id = another.id; self.name = another.name}` in an object and then `let object = ModelObject(from: dataObject)`

Comment: Your example code runs just fine for me, though I removed the Realm-specific stuff since I'm not faimilar with that. But I made `DataObject` inherit `NSObject` and the generic function was able to convert between the two.

Comment: @jjquirckart OP is trying to "keep their Persistence layer completely separated from the rest of the app", so maybe that's why?

Comment: @Max `dataObject` is probably of the existential type `MyProtocol` there, rather than `DataObject`

Comment: @Sweeper well, persistence layer doesn't have to know that someone somewhere defined an additional `init` - this is what extensions are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it

```
func buildObject<R: MyProtocol>(objectIn: MyProtocol, returnType: R.Type) -> R {
    let returnObject = returnType.init(id: objectIn.id, name: objectIn.name)
    return returnObject
}
```

the key observation: at no point do we need the concrete type of `objectIn`, so just require the protocol type.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. What if I'm also dealing with associated types in the Protocol? Ex: `associatedtype P: Collection where P.Element: MyOtherProtocol`? The Realm collection is "`List`" and in my Model collections I'm using "`Array`."

Comment: Usually that is solved with an additional generic parameter along with a `where` constraint, but it's hard to say without knowing more about your use case. I'd ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the other argument. The return type already provides the type information.

```swift
func buildObject<R: MyProtocol>(objectIn: some MyProtocol) -> R {
  .init(id: objectIn.id, name: objectIn.name)
}
```

As suggested in the comments, this is more idiomatically expressed as an initializer.

```swift
extension MyProtocol {
  init(_ objectIn: some MyProtocol) {
    self.init(id: objectIn.id, name: objectIn.name)
  }
}
```